# How to retrieve the texture color on an object at its intersection point with a ray

Tags: three.js

[Elevators (white) between Earth and a Tethered Ring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxyEV.jpg)

I'm developing a Three.js model of the Tethered Ring, which is a space access and transportation infrastructure project. I would like to add elevator cables (white) between the Tethered Ring and Earth *only where there is land*. I'd like to do this by:

1. Retrieving the color of the Earth's texture where the elevator cable's "ray" intersects the front face of the Earth's texture,
2. Comparing that color to blue, and
3. Adding the cable object only where the color is "not blue".

I would be very appreciative if someone could provide sample code for step 1!

(Note: This earlier post from 6 years ago gives clues but doesn't go into sufficient detail.
ref: [ThreeJS How to pick the intersection point color of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33433305/threejs-how-to-pick-the-intersection-point-color-of-an-object))

Comment: please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can run and test it.

Comment: I could put the project on GitHub, and provide a link. Would that work for you?

Comment: Yes , I will clone it.

Comment: Can you try this link: https://github.com/philipswan/TetheredRing? Note that there were file size limits that prevented me from uploading a texture and the contents of the node_modules folder.

Comment: you should use `gitignore`  which means that ignore that folder. because each person by the command `npm install` can create that. I will see your repo.

Comment: Thanks! BTW, I added some instructions on how to use keyboard shortcuts to help with navigation.

Comment: I also uploaded the right Earth texture to my website and provided instructions on how to retrieve it.