# Check if user is clicking on non-transparent part of a png?

Tags: javascript, html, png

Like the title suggests, I'd like to know if a user is clicking on the non-transparent part of a png.

Further - imagine there are several layers of pngs that are layered ontop of each other. Same size, but for each layer, the non-transparent part gets smaller and smaller. I'd like to be able to identify *which* of the pngs are being clicked by identifying which non-transparent part the user clicks on.

Comment: Are the dimensions and positions of each transparent section known?

Comment: Not really no, the user uploads x number of layers that are stacked ontop of each other. Generally, *smaller* items are placed higher up in the stack.

Comment: You might be able to do this by adding the overlapping images to a [canvas element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas).  On mouse click the code would need to drill down through the images to find the first non-transparent pixel. Yet, this is way beyond the scope of an SO question.  There is enough information in this other question to get you started: [How can I read a pixel of an image when user clicks it?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1041492/943435)

Answer (score 3):

Let's try using a canvas. Thanks to @Yogi from the comments.

```js
var url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png/420px-PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png";

var image = new Image();
image.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  canvas.width = image.width;
  canvas.height = image.height;
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(ev) {
    var cx = ev.offsetX
    var cy = ev.offsetY
    var data = context.getImageData(cx, cy, 1, 1).data;
    console.log(""+data)

  })
}
image.crossOrigin = "anonymous"
image.src = url;
```

```html
<body>
  click and get color in console.<br>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Mixing and matching the answers and comments above:

Attach a **click handler** for each png you've rendered. On click, the event will propagate from the top-most png of the stack (the first png the click "meets"), all the way to the bottom-most (the first one rendered).

The **handler** will execute the same logic for each png (you may reuse the same function):

1. Get the [relative coordinates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetX) of the click (relative to **each image**).
2. [Determine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67033212/12473000) if the pixel is transparent or not (this is the key the answer).
3. If it meets your criteria, record which png was clicked using [event.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget). Then, [stop propagating](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) the event, to prevent deeper pngs from recording an event as well.

If the png didn't meet your criteria, allow the event to keep propagating.