# How do I get the hexadecimal code of a color on my webpage?

Tags: css, colors, hex, color-picker

I have a web page which has a picture. That picture has a color.

I need the hex code of the color in that picture. How can I get it?

Comment: do you want to do this programmaticaly?

Comment: @Sinan: not neccisarrily - doctype maybe, but if you're handed a project, and told the colors must fit this photo, you'll need some way of knowing what colors to use. Especially since most clients don't have a clue...

Answer (score 12):

Get Firefox. Get the [ColorZilla plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/271). Click on ColorZilla. Move over the color you want. Voila! You have the hexadecimal codes.

Comment: ColorZilla is a very handy Firefox plugin! One more reason I can't develop in IE.

Comment: Even if there is a color picker in IE? And most of what you need from the Web Developer plugin is available in the IE Developer Toolbar?

Don't get me wrong, I like FX - but lets not go slamming things we don't understand.

Comment: 'Even if there is a color picker in IE?' -- ? Who has ever heard of a web developer shunning FireFox to develop in IE instead? Is color picking the only thing one will ever need? Have you heard of firebug? IE's developer toolbar is just an inferior cousin

Comment: Btw, I am slamming what? What is it in my answer that's slamming anything. Please highlight.

Comment: @Cyril: Wasn't referring to your answer - the @scunliffe got missing. Also while I wasn't saying to shun Fx, I was saying don't shun IE. Have you heard of a web developer shunning the browser with the largest market share?

Comment: I am not asking to shun IE Anon :). I am asking not to shun FX cause it's so developer friendly. I did earn some practical sense about market share over the years.

Comment: @Anon good point lol and thanks for the tip colour picker in IE is awesome!

Answer (score 3):

Another program to use is [ColorPic](http://www.iconico.com/colorpic/).

Answer (score 2):

The Internet Explorer developer toolbar (<kbd>F12</kbd> in Internet Explorer 8) has a colour picker in the *Tools* menu that should help you.

Firefox has a few add-ons available that do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

[ColorSchemer ColorPix](http://www.colorschemer.com/colorpix_info.php) is another good option. Light weight, and it gives you (among others) the RGB as well as the Hex for a given color.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in software, rather than manually, you could use a [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial) element in supported browsers - draw the image on the canvas, then extract the colour information of the desired pixel. See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667045/getpixel-from-html-canvas) for how.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Pixie](http://www.nattyware.com/pixie.php) from Nattyware. That is free and they also have a portable version.

Answer (score 0):

Take a screenshot and open it in a regular or sophisticated paint application to get the color. Or better: download the picture and open it in a paint application.

Comment: there is no way to get the hex of colors in paint

Comment: Not really. "Print Screen" to get the image, open image editor, paste (CTRL+V), select picker tool, read colour value.

Answer (score 0):

Take a screenshot of the page, open it in [Adobe Photoshop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Photoshop) and select that color with the dropper tool.

The *Color* dialog will show you the hexadecimal code, the RGB color and the CYMK color code for that. You can do the same in [GIMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIMP) if you don’t have Photoshop.