# How to get the color palette of a website using PHP?

Tags: php, css

I need to find the common colors used in a particular website.Most of the cases it will be body background,header background etc. But the problem is, some of the classes or IDs override other.So we cannot get the exact color patterns. Is there any way to find the exact color patterns of a website which browser picking?

Comment: This seems like a big task. What do you have so far?

Comment: An idea springs to my mind. Use a library like wkhtml2img to create a snapshot and then you can make a colour map based on it...

Comment: PHP is an **HTML text** preprocessor. it has nothing to with HTML **rendering**

Comment: Thanks for the response..

I just tried to get the screenshot of the particular page and using some built in function of php, extract the color palette from screenshot. But it have some limitation and the application speed also decreased.Am not sure it is the right way to sort out the problem..

Comment: @Jerin You could start the image anaylisis in a [`child process`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) and [`wait`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-wait.php) for the results ;-)

Comment: @YourCommonSense — PHP is a *programming language*, nothing stopping you writing an HTML renderer in it, or linking to an existing on, Selenium libraries already exist.

Comment: there are many websites that generate colour palette's from uploaded images so if a screenshot can be taken of the webpage then the rest is entirely possible.... somehow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Havelock pointed out, the idea that does come to mind is transforming the page into an image, and then getting the color-palette from that. It does however have a few problems:

1. There is no guarantee, that what the library returns is what the users seens in a particular browser, yet alone all.
2. The processing needed could be way easier implemented in other languages than PHP. I dont mean, that it cant be done, but it is just not well suited for this task.

If you do however continue along this path, I would recommend trying something with an API, to get your screenshots, and then just using some PHP to parse them. Example for such a service - http://browsershots.org/xmlrpc/

Answer (score 2):

There are several online services to extract colors from websites. Including image colors:

- http://www.colorcombos.com/grabcolors.html
- http://www.hextractor.com/
- [more...](https://www.google.com/search?q=extract%20colors%20from%20website)

A PHP class to extract colors from images can be found [here](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3370-PHP-Extracts-the-most-common-colors-used-in-images.html). See also [How do I get the Hex Code of a color on my webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340367/how-do-i-get-the-hex-code-of-a-color-on-my-webpage) 
Also a [FireFox Plugin](http://www.colorzilla.com/firefox/) exists.