# Is there a way to fill from a point till it hits a border using HTML Canvas and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have some old basic code I'm working with. It goes something like this:

`PAINT (200, 200), 2, 10`

This means essentially: fill an area beginning at coordinates: X 200 Y 200 with the color dark green until the point reaches a boundary color of light green, then stop filling.

The idea is that one can draw an outline (say of a state) using one color then fill the entire outline with another color. It doesn't fill the whole screen because the outline is of the color at which the fill stops.

Comment: so if you were to "fill the entire outline", does it do so in a scanning motion? like line by line? if so, how is the starting point determined? how does it handle concave shapes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I perform flood fill with HTML Canvas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106995/how-can-i-perform-flood-fill-with-html-canvas)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill#Stack-based_recursive_implementation_.28Four-way.29) to fill a region. It takes a starting point (or the **seed point**) as an input and recursively fills the region, by attempting to fill its empty neighbors.

A simple stack-based implementation in JavaScript:

```
// Takes the seed point as input
var floodfill = function(point) {
    var stack = Array();
    stack.push(point); // Push the seed
    while(stack.length > 0) {
        var currPoint = stack.pop();
        if(isEmpty(currPoint)) { // Check if the point is not filled
            setPixel(currPoint); // Fill the point with the foreground
            stack.push(currPoint.x + 1, currPoint.y); // Fill the east neighbour
            stack.push(currPoint.x, currPoint.y + 1); // Fill the south neighbour
            stack.push(currPoint.x - 1, currPoint.y); // Fill the west neighbour
            stack.push(currPoint.x, currPoint.y - 1); // Fill the north neighbour
        }
    }
};
```

`isEmpty(point)` is the function that tests whether the point `(x, y)` is filled with the boundary color (light green, in this case) or not.

`setPixel(point)` fills the point `(x, y)` with the foreground color (dark green, in your case).

The [implementation of these functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4899799/1492578) is trivial, and I leave it to you.

The implementation above uses a [4-connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_connectivity#4-connected) neighborhood. But it can easily be extended to 6 or 8-connected neighborhoods.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer! I'm a little confused on one point, I don't see how this knows what the boundary color is or the foreground color?

Comment: You could pass the background and foreground colors to the function as well, and have your `isEmpty` and `setPixel` use the same.