# How do I do flood fill on the HTML canvas in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, flood-fill

As attached in the link below is a screenshot of my canvas (outer box is the canvas). The inner box is a grey box and the line is a line drawn in the canvas. How do I create a flood fill function that fills the entire canvas (except the inner grey box as well as the line) with a specific color?

The function should accept three variables only, x y and color, as seen below, but I'm not sure how to continue:

```
floodFill(x, y, color) {
    this.canvasColor[x][y] = color;

    this.floodFill(x-1, y, color);
    this.floodFill(x+1, y, color);
    this.floodFill(x, y-1, color);
    this.floodFill(x, y+1, color);
}
```

[image: Canvas Image]

Comment: Just set the color of the whole canvas and then fill the inner box back with white

Comment: How the initial graphic is drawn? drawImage()? rect()? lineTo()?

Answer (score 9):

To create a flood fill you need to be able to look at the pixels that are there already and check they aren't the color you started with so something like this.

```js
const ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(20, 20);
ctx.lineTo(250, 70);
ctx.lineTo(270, 120);
ctx.lineTo(170, 140);
ctx.lineTo(190, 80);
ctx.lineTo(100, 60);
ctx.lineTo(50, 130);
ctx.lineTo(20, 20);
ctx.stroke();

floodFill(ctx, 40, 50, [255, 0, 0, 255]);

function getPixel(imageData, x, y) {
  if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= imageData.width || y >= imageData.height) {
    return [-1, -1, -1, -1];  // impossible color
  } else {
    const offset = (y * imageData.width + x) * 4;
    return imageData.data.slice(offset, offset + 4);
  }
}

function setPixel(imageData, x, y, color) {
  const offset = (y * imageData.width + x) * 4;
  imageData.data[offset + 0] = color[0];
  imageData.data[offset + 1] = color[1];
  imageData.data[offset + 2] = color[2];
  imageData.data[offset + 3] = color[0];
}

function colorsMatch(a, b) {
  return a[0] === b[0] && a[1] === b[1] && a[2] === b[2] && a[3] === b[3];
}

function floodFill(ctx, x, y, fillColor) {
  // read the pixels in the canvas
  const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  
  // get the color we're filling
  const targetColor = getPixel(imageData, x, y);
  
  // check we are actually filling a different color
  if (!colorsMatch(targetColor, fillColor)) {
  
    fillPixel(imageData, x, y, targetColor, fillColor);
    
    // put the data back
    ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
  }
}

function fillPixel(imageData, x, y, targetColor, fillColor) {
  const currentColor = getPixel(imageData, x, y);
  if (colorsMatch(currentColor, targetColor)) {
    setPixel(imageData, x, y, fillColor);
    fillPixel(imageData, x + 1, y, targetColor, fillColor);
    fillPixel(imageData, x - 1, y, targetColor, fillColor);
    fillPixel(imageData, x, y + 1, targetColor, fillColor);
    fillPixel(imageData, x, y - 1, targetColor, fillColor);
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

There's at least 2 problems with this code though.

1. It's deeply recursive.

   So you might run out of stack space
2. It's slow.

   No idea if it's too slow but JavaScript in the browser is mostly single threaded so while this code is running the browser is frozen. For a large canvas that frozen time might make the page really slow and if it's frozen too long the browser will ask if the user wants to kill the page.

The solution to running out of stack space is to implement our own stack. For example instead of recursively calling `fillPixel` we could keep an array of positions we want to look at. We'd add the 4 positions to that array and then pop things off the array until it's empty

```js
const ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(20, 20);
ctx.lineTo(250, 70);
ctx.lineTo(270, 120);
ctx.lineTo(170, 140);
ctx.lineTo(190, 80);
ctx.lineTo(100, 60);
ctx.lineTo(50, 130);
ctx.lineTo(20, 20);
ctx.stroke();

floodFill(ctx, 40, 50, [255, 0, 0, 255]);

function getPixel(imageData, x, y) {
  if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= imageData.width || y >= imageData.height) {
    return [-1, -1, -1, -1];  // impossible color
  } else {
    const offset = (y * imageData.width + x) * 4;
    return imageData.data.slice(offset, offset + 4);
  }
}

function setPixel(imageData, x, y, color) {
  const offset = (y * imageData.width + x) * 4;
  imageData.data[offset + 0] = color[0];
  imageData.data[offset + 1] = color[1];
  imageData.data[offset + 2] = color[2];
  imageData.data[offset + 3] = color[0];
}

function colorsMatch(a, b) {
  return a[0] === b[0] && a[1] === b[1] && a[2] === b[2] && a[3] === b[3];
}

function floodFill(ctx, x, y, fillColor) {
  // read the pixels in the canvas
  const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  
  // get the color we're filling
  const targetColor = getPixel(imageData, x, y);
  
  // check we are actually filling a different color
  if (!colorsMatch(targetColor, fillColor)) {
  
    const pixelsToCheck = [x, y];
    while (pixelsToCheck.length > 0) {
      const y = pixelsToCheck.pop();
      const x = pixelsToCheck.pop();
      
      const currentColor = getPixel(imageData, x, y);
      if (colorsMatch(currentColor, targetColor)) {
        setPixel(imageData, x, y, fillColor);
        pixelsToCheck.push(x + 1, y);
        pixelsToCheck.push(x - 1, y);
        pixelsToCheck.push(x, y + 1);
        pixelsToCheck.push(x, y - 1);
      }
    }
    
    // put the data back
    ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

The solution to it being too slow is either to [make it run a little at a time](http://jsfiddle.net/greggman/75kLyetr/) OR to move it to a worker. I think that's a little too much to show in the same answer though [here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/greggman/La72ghf8/). I tested the code above on a 4096x4096 canvas and it took 16 seconds to fill a blank canvas on my machine so yes it's arguably too slow but putting it in a worker brings new problems which is that the result will be asynchronous so even though the browser wouldn't freeze you'd probably want to prevent the user from doing something until it finishes.

Another issue is you'll see the lines are antialiased and so filling with a solid color fills close the the line but not all the way up to it. To fix that you can change `colorsMatch` to check for *close enough* but then you have a new problem that if `targetColor` and `fillColor` are also *close enough* it will keep trying to fill itself. You could solve that by making another array, one byte or one bit per pixel to track places you've ready checked.

```js
const ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(20, 20);
ctx.lineTo(250, 70);
ctx.lineTo(270, 120);
ctx.lineTo(170, 140);
ctx.lineTo(190, 80);
ctx.lineTo(100, 60);
ctx.lineTo(50, 130);
ctx.lineTo(20, 20);
ctx.stroke();

floodFill(ctx, 40, 50, [255, 0, 0, 255], 128);

function getPixel(imageData, x, y) {
  if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= imageData.width || y >= imageData.height) {
    return [-1, -1, -1, -1];  // impossible color
  } else {
    const offset = (y * imageData.width + x) * 4;
    return imageData.data.slice(offset, offset + 4);
  }
}

function setPixel(imageData, x, y, color) {
  const offset = (y * imageData.width + x) * 4;
  imageData.data[offset + 0] = color[0];
  imageData.data[offset + 1] = color[1];
  imageData.data[offset + 2] = color[2];
  imageData.data[offset + 3] = color[0];
}

function colorsMatch(a, b, rangeSq) {
  const dr = a[0] - b[0];
  const dg = a[1] - b[1];
  const db = a[2] - b[2];
  const da = a[3] - b[3];
  return dr * dr + dg * dg + db * db + da * da < rangeSq;
}

function floodFill(ctx, x, y, fillColor, range = 1) {
  // read the pixels in the canvas
  const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  
  // flags for if we visited a pixel already
  const visited = new Uint8Array(imageData.width, imageData.height);
  
  // get the color we're filling
  const targetColor = getPixel(imageData, x, y);
  
  // check we are actually filling a different color
  if (!colorsMatch(targetColor, fillColor)) {

    const rangeSq = range * range;
    const pixelsToCheck = [x, y];
    while (pixelsToCheck.length > 0) {
      const y = pixelsToCheck.pop();
      const x = pixelsToCheck.pop();
      
      const currentColor = getPixel(imageData, x, y);
      if (!visited[y * imageData.width + x] &&
           colorsMatch(currentColor, targetColor, rangeSq)) {
        setPixel(imageData, x, y, fillColor);
        visited[y * imageData.width + x] = 1;  // mark we were here already
        pixelsToCheck.push(x + 1, y);
        pixelsToCheck.push(x - 1, y);
        pixelsToCheck.push(x, y + 1);
        pixelsToCheck.push(x, y - 1);
      }
    }
    
    // put the data back
    ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Note that this version of `colorsMatch` is using is kind of naieve. It might be better to convert to HSV or something or maybe you want to weight by alpha. I don't know what a good metric is for matching colors.

### Update

Another way to speed things up is of course to just optimize the code. Kaiido pointed out an obvious speedup which is to use a `Uint32Array` view on the pixels. That way looking up a pixel and setting a pixel there's just one 32bit value to read or write. [Just that change makes it about 4x faster](http://jsfiddle.net/greggman/wpfd8he1/). It still takes 4 seconds to fill a 4096x4096 canvas though. There might be other optimization like instead of calling `getPixels` make that inline but don't push a new pixel on our list of pixels to check if they are out of range. It might be 10% speed up (no idea) but won't make it fast enough to be an interactive speed.

There are other speedups like checking across a row at a time since rows are cache friendly and you can compute the offset to a row once and use that while checking the entire row where as now for every pixel we have to compute the offset multiple times.

Those will complicate the algorithm so they are best left for you to figure out.

#### update:

faster algo at the end of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106995/how-can-i-perform-flood-fill-with-html-canvas/56221940#56221940)

Comment: For a flood-fill, you'd better work from an Uint32Array. *getPixel* becomes a simple lookup, and setPixel is a single op.

Comment: Good point, though checking closeness becomes 0.1% harder :P

Comment: my old pc made a suicide when I set filling point outside of the polygon (floodFill(ctx, 0, 0, [255, 0, 0, 255], 128);)

Comment: are there any example code doing that by using Uint32Array ?

Comment: @ChanwooPark there's a link to a version using `Uint32Array` in the answer near the bottom

Comment: @gman are there any possible ways to convert hex color (for example, #2268d8) or rgba value to form of 0xFF000000 ?

Comment: There is plenty of code around the net to do that but the creative solution would be to make a 1x1 pixel canvas, set fillStyle to the color you want, fill the 1x1 pixel, call getImageData to get the pixel, get a Uint32Array view on those pixel

Comment: can you elaborate more about colorMatching algorithm that can fill pixels without omitting pixels? 
`function colorsMatch(a, b, rangeSq) {
  const dr = a[0] - b[0];
  const dg = a[1] - b[1];
  const db = a[2] - b[2];
  const da = a[3] - b[3];
  return dr * dr + dg * dg + db * db + da * da < rangeSq; //especially this line
}` (why is this code block formed so ugly in comment)
what does square of each color valued summed up being smaller than square of range value mean?

Comment: It's just distance from a point. The distance between 2 points is the square root of  the sum of the squares of the difference between each component. `length = sqrt(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2)` is the same as `distance = sqrt((ax - bx)^2 + (ay - by)^2 + (az - bz)^2 + (aw - bw)^2)` but sqrt is slow so if all you want to do is check `distance < maxDistance` you can just as easily compare `distanceSq < maxDistanceSq` and avoid having to take the square root. Comparing colors though is a perceptual issue. You should google perceptual color comparison algorithms or something if you want other solutions

Comment: @gman hello again : ) the Uint32Array version of bucket fill run out of call stack when trying to bucketfill non-closed drawings. I assume there isn't defending logic of keep pushing pixels to the stack. any good idea for this situation?

Comment: There is no stack so I don’t know what you mean about running out of stack. The algorithm above is just the simplest version, not designed to be efficient. If you want a more efficient version do more work in each iteration. For example draw left, right, up, and down until and check perpendicular to see if you need to add new places to check, only add new places if they aren’t already visited and if you haven’t already added a neighboring pixel. I’m sure there are 1000s of ways to speed it up and use less memory.

Comment: A simple change is probably to change  `pixelsToCheck.push(x + 1, y)` to `pushPixelToCheckOnlyIfNotAMatch(x + 1, y)` and write a function that checks if that pixel actually needs to be added to the array of things to check.

Comment: Lots of other algorithms [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) and [here](http://www.adammil.net/blog/v126_A_More_Efficient_Flood_Fill.html)