# How to get the average or main color from an image with javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

what i want is to the the HEX or the RGB average value from an image to the another div background this color.

So if i upload an image with a ot of red i get something like #FF0000 just as an example.

Let Me know if this is posible :)

Many thanks.

Comment: JavaScript can't handle uploaded files by itself.

Comment: Do you want the exact pixel color only, or within a particular HSV range? (I'd suggest that the latter will serve you better.)

Answer (score 13):

First, draw the image on a `canvas`:

```
function draw(img) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
    c.width = canvas.width = img.width;
    c.height = canvas.height = img.height;
    c.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    c.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width , img.height);
    return c; // returns the context
}
```

You can now iterate over the image's pixels. A naive approach for color-detection is to simply count the frequency of each color in the image.

```
// returns a map counting the frequency of each color
// in the image on the canvas
function getColors(c) {
    var col, colors = {};
    var pixels, r, g, b, a;
    r = g = b = a = 0;
    pixels = c.getImageData(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    for (var i = 0, data = pixels.data; i < data.length; i += 4) {
        r = data[i];
        g = data[i + 1];
        b = data[i + 2];
        a = data[i + 3]; // alpha
        // skip pixels >50% transparent
        if (a < (255 / 2))
            continue; 
        col = rgbToHex(r, g, b);
        if (!colors[col])
            colors[col] = 0;
        colors[col]++;
    }
    return colors;
}

function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
    if (r > 255 || g > 255 || b > 255)
        throw "Invalid color component";
    return ((r << 16) | (g << 8) | b).toString(16);
}
```

`getColors` returns a map of color names and counts. Transparent pixels are skipped. It should be trivial to get the most-frequently seen color from this map.

If you literally want an *average* of each color component, you could easily get that from the results of `getColors`, too, but the results aren't likely to be very useful. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541481/get-average-color-of-image-via-javascript) explains a much better approach.

You can use it all like this:

```
// nicely formats hex values
function pad(hex) {
    return ("000000" + hex).slice(-6);
}

// see this example working in the fiddle below
var info = document.getElementById("info");
var img = document.getElementById("squares");
var colors = getColors(draw(img));
for (var hex in colors) {
    info.innerHTML += "<li>" + pad(hex) + "->" + colors[hex];
}
```

See a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/WZVWL/42/).

Answer (score 4):

- Put image on canvas.
- Get 2D context.
- Loop through pixels, and store each r,g,b value. If you find the same, increment it once.
- Loop through stored r,g,b values and take note of largest r,g,b value.
- [Convert r,g,b to hex](http://programming.top54u.com/post/Javascript-Convert-RGB-to-Hex.aspx).

Comment: 19 lines to convert RGB to hex? Kids these days. `((r << 16) | (g << 8) | b)`

Comment: @lwburk Yeah I know, Google finds answers but rarely the best. That's why people on here *did you Google first?* annoy me.

Answer (score 3):

This is only possible using the canvas tag as described here :

http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html-5-canvas-the-basics/#pixelbasedmanipulation

Of course this is only available in newer browsers

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using the convolution filters css allows you to apply.  This might be able to get the effect you're going for ( assuming you're wanting to present it back into the html).  So you could display the image twice , one convolved.

That being said, doesn't really work if you need the information yourself for some purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Update 2023: There is a javascript lib to do just that: 
**Color Thief** - https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/color-thief/

> Grab the color palette from an image using just Javascript. Works in
> the browser and in Node.

Answer (score -1):

For finding that average color:

1. Put Image on Canvas
2. Resize image to 1px by 1px
3. Get the color of the resulting pixel(This pixel will be the calculated average)