# Pixel RGB with ImageMagick and Rails

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, paperclip, rmagick

I'm currently uploading an image with PaperClip and ImageMagick. I would like to get the image's average color so I'm doing this (with a before_create hook):

```
def get_average_color           
    img =  Magick::Image.read(self.url).first
    pix = img.scale(1, 1)
    averageColor = pix.pixel_color(0,0)
end
```

This works but when I try to print the pixel colors out I get them like this:

```
red=36722, green=44474, blue=40920, opacity=0
```

How can I get these RGB values into regular (0-255) RGB values. Do I just mod them? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ImageMagick is compiled for a quantum depth of 16 bits, versus 8 bits. See [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20140513190943/http://rubyforge.org/forum/forum.php?thread_id=10975&forum_id=1618) in the RMagick Hints & Tips Forum for more information.

Comment: This definitely helps. I ended up just dividing the RGB values by 257 (QuantumDepth 16 / QuantumDepth 8).

Comment: Maybe also look at the quantize method http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image3.html#quantize.

Answer (score 3):

If ImageMagick is compiled with a quantum depth of 16 bits, and you need the 8 bit values,
you can use bitwise operation:

```
r_8bit = r_16bit & 255;
g_8bit = g_16bit & 255;
b_8bit = b_16bit & 255;
```

Bitwise operation are much more faster ;)

You can use also this way:

```
IMAGE_MAGICK_8BIT_MASK = 0b0000000011111111
r_8bit = (r_16bit & IMAGE_MAGICK_8BIT_MASK)
...
```

Now a little bit of Math:

```
x_16bit = x_8bit*256 + x_8bit = x_8bit<<8 | x_8bit
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily get 8-bit encoded color using this approach:

```
averageColor = pix.pixel_color(0,0).to_color(Magick::AllCompliance, false, 8, true)
```

You can get more details at https://rmagick.github.io/struct.html (to_color paragraph)