# rmagick pixel color value

Tags: ruby, colors, bitmap, rmagick, depth

I am using rmagick to deal with getting a each single pixel of a bitmap. I need to get the values of colors in depth of 8 (256 colors), but unfortunately when i use pixel.[color] (pixel. red for example), i am getting them in depth of 16. It is happening even after i used image.quantize(256).

Here is the code:

```
require 'RMagick'
include Magick

image = ImageList.new("image.bmp")
image3 = image.quantize(number_colors = 256)
puts image3.number_colors

image2 = Image.new(image.columns, image.rows)

(0..image.columns).each do |x|
    (0..image.rows).each do |y|
        pixel = image3.pixel_color(x, y)

    print pixel.red
    print ", "
    print pixel.green
    print ", "
    print pixel.blue
    print "\n"

    image2.pixel_color(x, y, pixel)
    end
end
```

What should I to get just values of 0..255?

Comment: Already discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499161/pixel-rgb-with-imagemagick-and-rails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are stored in a 'quantum depth' of 16-bits. You can rebuild the library to change this. Or you can simply divide each value by 257.

There's a function called MagickExportImagePixels which can get you the 8-bit pixel data that you want. Whenever you perform a transformation etc on an image it will get converted back to 16-bit pixels.

Comment: Because 256 * 255 = 65280. 257 * 255 = 65535, therefore giving you the full range when converting 16 bit to 8 bit

Comment: You forgot about flooring. Your *257 * 255 = 65535* proves, that only one of 65536 colors would be converted to 255 -- all lower would be 254. The proper convertion to one-byte data is right shift by 8 bits, i.e. division by 256.

Comment: You can argue this with the ImageMagick developers if you want. That's what they have suggested.

Comment: I do not see any ImageMagick developer here. While it is enough to be modern 10-years old kid to know math enough to agree with me.

Comment: I did some experiments dividing by both 256 and 257 truncate to the same values. In either case, I get a 0-255 number that matches exactly what my image editing program describes as the pixel values.