# rmagick color out of range

Tags: ruby, image, rmagick

I am trying to average the colours in an image, I have come up with the following script (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5164917/1198291)):

**scrip.rb:**

```
require 'rmagick'
file = "./img.jpg"
img = Magick::Image.read(file).first
color = img.scale(1, 1).pixel_color(0,0)
p [color.red, color.green, color.blue]
```

**`img.jpg:`**
[image]

BUT the RGB output is `[31829, 30571, 27931]`.

Questions:

1. Shouldn't the numbers be in the range of `[0-255]`?
2. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have there is the red, green, and blue *histogram* values.

You need to divide by `256` in order to get each RGB value. In this case, the RGB values are:

```
require 'rmagick'
file = "./img.jpg"
img = Magick::Image.read(file).first
color = img.scale(1, 1).pixel_color(0,0)
p [color.red/256, color.green/256, color.blue/256]
  # => [124, 119, 109]
```

[This blog post](http://blog.kellishaver.com/image-color-analysis-with-rmagick/) provides a more thorough explanation on how to analyse images with `RMagick`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the odd output is due to the bit depth. As a previous answer states, "They are stored in a 'quantum depth' of 16-bits." This was an initial assumption, but by looking at previous answers, this makes more sense. In order to properly convert these numbers back to your typically desires [0-255] range, you must divide the values by 256.

Note: You can change the quantum depth during runtime. When reading the file, you should be able to use a block like shown in the following code.

```
img = Magick::Image.read(file){self.depth = 8}.first
```