# Grab 2 hex colors automatically base on an image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

## My goal

is to find a way to grab a **2** hex colors automatically base on an image.

The 2 colors should be selected base on the majority/percentages of the color appearance, excluding (white+black color).

## Ex.

Base on this logo

[image]

I should get back these 2 hex base on the logo

- Orange = `#F48024`
- Grey  = `#BCBBBB`

---

## Ex 2.

Base on this logo

[image]

I should get back these 2 hex base on the logo

- Red = `#EF0101`
- Blue = `#2C32A8`

---

**Is there a frameworks/API that help me achieve that?**

I'm not looking to re-invented the wheel here.

Comment: Try [Vibrant.js](http://jariz.github.io/vibrant.js/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the average or main color from an image with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162828/how-to-get-the-average-or-main-color-from-an-image-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to check these details

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.setAttribute('src', 'examples/octocat.png')

img.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var vibrant = new Vibrant(img);
    var swatches = vibrant.swatches()
    for (var swatch in swatches)
        if (swatches.hasOwnProperty(swatch) && swatches[swatch])
            console.log(swatch, swatches[swatch].getHex())
});
```

Output

> - Results into:
> - Vibrant #7a4426
> - Muted #7b9eae
> - DarkVibrant #348945
> - DarkMuted #141414
> - LightVibrant #f3ccb4

Source from https://github.com/jariz/vibrant.js/