# Getting dominant color of an image

Tags: python, image, colors, python-imaging-library

How can I get the dominant color of an image as rgb or hexcode?

I found a script called [Color Thief](https://github.com/fengsp/color-thief-py) but it does not allow image URLs only paths.

Comment: I assume you're using javascript?

Comment: Color Thief uses jQuery, but if there’s another solution (PHP or whatever) I’d love to use that instead.

Comment: For PHP, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730661/how-to-find-the-dominant-color-in-image

Answer (score 0):

use `urllib` to download the image first, then delete the unnecessary file:

```
from colorthief import ColorThief
import urllib
import os
def dominant_color_from_url(url,tmp_file='tmp.jpg'):
    '''Downloads ths image file and analyzes the dominant color'''
    urllib.urlretrieve(url, tmp_file)
    color_thief = ColorThief(tmp_file)
    dominant_color = color_thief.get_color(quality=1)
    os.remove(tmp_file)
    return dominant_color
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to download unnecessary file, do it this way:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

if sys.version_info < (3, 0):
    from urllib2 import urlopen
else:
    from urllib.request import urlopen

import io

from colorthief import ColorThief


fd = urlopen('http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/color-thief/img/photo1.jpg')
f = io.BytesIO(fd.read())
color_thief = ColorThief(f)
print(color_thief.get_color(quality=1))
print(color_thief.get_palette(quality=1))
```