# Get dominant colour from image to use as a background whilst image pre-loads

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to recreate an effect being used on [pinterest](http://www.pinterest.com/) at the moment to preload images. When you go on the page you'll notice each image has its own colour background that's been selected from the pre-loading image. How would I go about creating this effect?

Any jsfiddle examples of possible solutions would be hugely appreciated

Comment: since you want to know the color before the image arrives on the client, you'll have to do in with PHP on the server-side. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8730762/214446

Answer (score 0):

Interesting idea.

May not be exactly what you are looking for but PHPthumb makes a thumbnail of an image on the fly. A very small thumbnail that has been blurred will only be the whitewash, background, or  color tone of the image.

Clearly there will be a need to cache the color images to remove potential performance issues.

ImageMagick http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php would be required to do the image processing on the server, with phpthumb.

other php image processing options are documented http://php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.image.php