# How to detect a blank or white space in an Image with PHP?

Tags: php, image

I have an image with a blank rectangular white area where a user can upload their image and have it embedded in it. My question is, how do I find the coordinates and dimension of the said blank area with PHP?

Comment: you should use HTML5 Canvas. check this http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730661/how-to-find-the-dominant-color-in-image