# Programmatically check image element colors and percentage of colors

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, image, colors

i was wondering if is out there any way to detect used color in an image and his percentage related to all the other colors used.

I'm searching for any good php / javascript / jquery solution.

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: can be done using javascript and canvas: [get average color of image via javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541481/get-average-color-of-image-via-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is iterate the image pixel by pixel with [imagecolorat](http://php.net/imagecolorat) function and  create your own percentage.

You can also use [`imagecolorsforindex`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorsforindex.php) for this.

Answer (score 1):

In php, this might be a good place to start peeking regarding images http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php