# CSS colour visibility issue

Tags: jquery, css, visibility, rgba

This is going to seem like a very odd question, but I have the following problem:

[image]

As you can see, when the image is a darker colour, the pagination doesn't show clearly.

I want to change the pagination colour dependant on the image colour beneath.

Is this possible with rgb/css? Alternately with Javascript?

Comment: it would be easier if you provide us with HTML too...

Comment: Why do you need HTML for this? I've clearly outlined the problem in the image...

Comment: maybe this helps:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541481/get-average-color-of-image-via-javascript][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541481/get-average-color-of-image-via-javascript

Comment: if we can see the HTML we'll know what elements are available for styling.

Comment: Why don't you just use Javascript and apply different styles.

Comment: Why do you need HTML for this? -- Its a convenient way to try to gain upvoted without actually offering nay help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you make a different design approach rather than using JS. Try adding a `border` with light shade of grey that will work in every background. See this demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/fqZf4/3/

Comment: This is actually what I ended up doing :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a 50% rgba for example:

```
element {
color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

This will make the font white and set the opacity to 50%. You could get the same effect with:

```
element {
opacity: 0.5;
color: rgb(255,255,255);
}
```

Notice the first method is still not supported in all Browsers.

To prevent the pagination to hide on white background, you could use a text shadow:

```
element {
text-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #000;
}
```

(See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-shadow.asp))

Comment: This is a nice method, but the pagination doesn't isn't quite visible enough on darker images unfortunately.

Comment: What if the background is at the same color tone as the opacity? You still lose visibility of pagination.

Comment: Then you could give the font a light background (background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2) for example).

Comment: Our use text-shadow, as described above

Comment: That's not a proper solution if images are loaded dynamically and you can't test case for every image that is about to load.

Answer (score 1):

If you can store a value with the image you can use the `data-*`-attribute:

```
// images that are dark gets the new attribute
<img src="" alt="">
<img src="" alt="" data-invert="true">

// let's say this is you pagination
<nav id="pagination">
    // your pagination elements
</nav>
```

Than you can update your slide function (this is just pseudocode):

```
function slide() {
    // lets say you know the current image and there's an array of images
    var current = 1;
    if ('true' == images.eq(current).attr('data-invert') {
        $('pagination').addClass('invert');
    } else {
        $('pagination').removeClass('invert');
    }
}
```

And the class `invert` has simply a brighter color scheme that looks good on darker images.

Answer (score 0):

Give grey text shadow to your text. It will work perfectly.