# Change Text Color According to Image

Tags: jquery, css, image

I'm trying to figure out a way to change the color of some text via jQuery.

Essentially, I have a div with a random loading image. Over that I have div containing some text.

What I would like to happen is when a specific image is loaded it swaps the text color from white to black.

Anyone point me in the right direction?

**For clarification:**

My question is how do I find which image has been loaded into a div then execute a function based on thet result. For example:

I have 2 image, which are randomly loaded into a  via backstretch.js. I also have another div with some text overlaid on-top of the image:

```
<!-- my images -->
image-1.jpg
image-2.jpg

<!-- Layout -->
<div id="imageDIV"></div>
<div id="textDiv"><p>hello</p></div>
```

Once page has loaded and an image has been loaded into the div. Check which one it is then do somthing. So

```
if { 
   image is image-1.jpg then add a class to #textDiv
}

else if { 
   image is image-2.jpg add this class instead
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming you want to change text black/white vice versa so that it can be legible ontop of the image? See this question, related to what you're trying to achieve: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541481/get-average-color-of-image-via-javascript

Comment: how is the image loaded? could you add your code?

Comment: are you always going to be switching from white to black text?

Comment: (sweetamylass) Yes, it's for legibility. I'll check your link, thanks - (superUnited) its loaded using backstretch.js http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/ - (David Chase) Yeah just black and white.

Comment: Would there be a way which just checks the URL/SRC of the image and if its say image1.jpeg then use color: black else use color: white?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [color-thief](https://github.com/lokesh/color-thief)
to get the dominant color of the image

```
    myImage = $('#myImage');  
    dominantColor = getDominantColor(myImage);  
    paletteArray = createPalette(myImage, 10); // 2nd argument sets th`e # of colors in palette
```

Comment: I'll have a look at this - Thanks

Comment: Another very fast way to get dominant color is to resize image to 1x1 pixel.