# Dominant colour from external image

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am loading in external images into my app and I want to get the dominant colour from the image and apply it to a separate div as a background-color in a rgba format

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [get average color of image via javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541481/get-average-color-of-image-via-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. I would say that if possible, any image processing should be done on server side, but if you must do it in javascript, Pixastic is a javascript image library. You can use the histogram function to get an array of colors in the image, then find the most common one from that array.

http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/histogram/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the *dominant* color is simply the most frequently used, I'd just draw it to a `canvas` element and use `getImageData()` to determine it.