# setting font color by taking image average color

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an interesting HTML5 project where i need to set the font color by taking out the average of background image. For example this is my background which has two textboxes textbox1 and textbox2.

[Image](http://i.share.pho.to/dc164d20_o.jpeg)

In order to get the color of textbox1 i need to calculate the average of the background image portion and then set the color. Similarly for textbox2 i need to calculate the average of its background image and then set the color .I can get the textbox positions but how can i calculate the average colors?I am very confused. Any recommendations of how can it be done using jquery or css?? 
.

Comment: check out this project http://briangonzalez.github.io/jquery.adaptive-backgrounds.js/

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541481/get-average-color-of-image-via-javascript

Comment: this is calculating the average of whole image whereas i just need a average of only text part of the image

Comment: Why don't you make an image of text part from original image? Comment is not a perfect answer but a good hint for you.

Comment: @Fumu7 what do you mean by making an image of text part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getAverageRGB(imgEl) {

    var blockSize = 5, // only visit every 5 pixels
        defaultRGB = {r:0,g:0,b:0}, // for non-supporting envs
        canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
        context = canvas.getContext && canvas.getContext('2d'),
        data, width, height,
        i = -4,
        length,
        rgb = {r:0,g:0,b:0},
        count = 0;

    if (!context) {
        return defaultRGB;
    }

    height = canvas.height = imgEl.naturalHeight || imgEl.offsetHeight || imgEl.height;
    width = canvas.width = imgEl.naturalWidth || imgEl.offsetWidth || imgEl.width;

    context.drawImage(imgEl, 0, 0);

    try {
        data = context.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
    } catch(e) {
        /* security error, img on diff domain */alert('x');
        return defaultRGB;
    }

    length = data.data.length;

    while ( (i += blockSize * 4) < length ) {
        ++count;
        rgb.r += data.data[i];
        rgb.g += data.data[i+1];
        rgb.b += data.data[i+2];
    }

    // ~~ used to floor values
    rgb.r = ~~(rgb.r/count);
    rgb.g = ~~(rgb.g/count);
    rgb.b = ~~(rgb.b/count);

    return rgb;

}
```

Usage:

```
var rgb = getAverageRGB(document.getElementById('image'));
```

Example:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb('+rgb.r+','+rgb.b+','+rgb.g+')';
```

Source: [Get average color of image via Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541481/get-average-color-of-image-via-javascript)

Comment: actually i just need the average of the selected text part