# Automatically select the card background color according to the color tone of the image

Tags: javascript, html

I have a point in my development, I’m waiting for your help.

As you can see in the following image, the description field of the image is automatically created according to the main color of the image. How can I do that ?

[image: Picture here]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541481/get-average-color-of-image-via-javascript Hope that helps

Comment: thanks bro,
it didn't work.
does not work with normal link. What are the lines of code to replace?