# Set average image color to multiple elements background

Tags: javascript, loops, each

newbie question here:
I have a code that find the average color of an image and apply that color to a sibling DIV's background color. The code works only for the first image of the page, but I want it to loop through all the images of the page that has the .project-thumbnail class, and apply the color to their respective sibling DIV.

I know I could do a jQuery's `.each()` function but I'm new to JavaScript and can't figure it out how to achieve the desired - without using jQuery

```
const img = document.querySelector('.project-thumbnail');
const rect = img.nextElementSibling;
img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";


img.onload = function () {
    getAverageColor(img)
}


function getAverageColor(img) {
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  let width = canvas.width || img.naturalWidth;
  let height = canvas.height || img.naturalHeight;
  let draw = ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

  const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
  const data = imageData.data;
  let r = 0;
  let g = 0;
  let b = 0;

  for (let i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i += 4) {
    r += data[i];
    g += data[i+1];
    b += data[i+2];
  }
  
  r = Math.floor(r / (data.length / 4));
  g = Math.floor(g / (data.length / 4));
  b = Math.floor(b / (data.length / 4));
  console.log("R:",r,"G:",g,"B:",b)
  //return { r: r, g: g, b: b };
 rect.style.background = `rgb(${r},${g},${b})`;
}

getAverageColor(img)
```

Comment: [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: `querySelectorAll()` + `.forEach()`

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I tried :
const img = document.querySelectorAll('.project-thumbnail');

but it doesn't work, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't know, you didn't add any html. What does it mean *doesn't work*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass a function (i.e: `setBgFromAverage`) to [NodeList.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) (NodeList being the result nodes of `document.querySelectorAll('.project-thumbnail')`)

Fix also your canvas size!

```js
const getAverageColor = (img) => {

  const rect = img.nextElementSibling;
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  const width = canvas.width = img.naturalWidth;
  const height = canvas.height = img.naturalHeight;

  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
  
  const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
  const data = imageData.data;
  let r = 0;
  let g = 0;
  let b = 0;

  for (let i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i += 4) {
    r += data[i];
    g += data[i + 1];
    b += data[i + 2];
  }

  r = Math.floor(r / (data.length / 4));
  g = Math.floor(g / (data.length / 4));
  b = Math.floor(b / (data.length / 4));

  rect.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${r},${g},${b})`;
};

const setBgFromAverage = (img) => {
  img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
  img.addEventListener("load", () => getAverageColor(img));
};

document.querySelectorAll('.project-thumbnail').forEach(setBgFromAverage);
```

```css
.projects {
  display: flex;
}

.project-thumbnail {
  height: 100px;
}

.project-thumbnail+* {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="projects">

  <img class="project-thumbnail" alt="thumb 1" src="https://graph.facebook.com/10217909169392394/picture?type=large">
  <div>Samuel Charpentier</div>
  
  <img class="project-thumbnail" alt="thumb 2" src="https://i.imgur.com/shlgPmb.jpeg">
  <div>Catty cat</div>
  
</div>
```

---

For an improved code to retrieve the **average color of an image** see this answer: [Get average color of image via Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73452020/383904)

Comment: Cool! You're welcome @SamuelCharpentier improved the code and added a useful link to a similar question.