# Copy a canvas node from a jquery object not in the DOM tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, prototypal-inheritance

I have been working on a game engine for the last little while and I recently added what i call a shadow DOM. All it is a jQuery object that contains a div so i can append things to it. Every time a frame is elapsed the contents of the shadow DOM is copied to multiple viewports. My problem is that I can't copy the state of the canvas elements.

Is there anyway to get around this without having to update each canvas element in each viewport?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the best way to do this is by creating another canvas then adding the data from the old canvas directly to the new one in the following way:

```
//Create a blank canvas to apply the old canvas to
var newCanvas = jQuery('<canvas></canvas>'),
    newCanvasContext = newCanvas.getContext('2d');

//size the new canvas to mirror the old canvas
newCanvas[0].width = oldCanvas[0].width;
newCanvas[0].height = oldCanvas[0].height;

//copy the old canvas onto the new canvas with drawImage();
newCanvasContext.drawImage(oldCanvas[0], 0, 0, oldCanvas[0].width, oldCanvas[0].height);
```

I found that **just copying the canvas node is not enough**. The **above is needed to duplicate** a canvas and **its data**.

Answer (score 1):

There's an excellent answer to your question right here on SO: [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. I had to copy the image data manually for each copy of the canvas. See [Any way to clone HTML5 canvas element with its content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318565/any-way-to-clone-html5-canvas-element-with-its-content) for details.