# How to create a minimap for large maps? (HTML5-javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary

[image: game map and minimap]

I'll try to explain what i'm trying to do.

I shared a photo. Left side, there's a game screen and it show me a little big area of full map. But I need to make a minimap like right side to look other places that opened areas. (Black places are none-visited places. And they're under the darkness like other strategy games)

The problem is that: I've recorded all tiles to my database. For example (x:1, y:1 = grass, x:1, y:2=grass, x:3, y:20= water...) And I'm showing tiles from database records.

So that, if I make a minimap from my database, it means i have to paste 10.000tiles at once. It means very very very very slow thing. I can paste map as an image at once, but if I do this, i can't define none-visited areas. If i take them from database, it will be very slow.

How can I create a minimap to control map vision?
What should I do?

Comment: Minimap does not need to have super high resolution - at least for me as a player. If you render every third/fourth tile it should be ok, and there'll be much less pixels to render.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5? So I suppose that everything is on a canvas, than just clone and resize the canvas with the big map to create a small one. **[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318565/any-way-to-clone-html5-canvas-element-with-its-content)** is a SO answer which may help you to do that.

Comment: the problem is that: i should make minimap dinamic from my database records. and if i call 10.000 records to show minimap, it gets me slow.

Comment: But how do you create the big map?

Comment: Why is a problem for you to create just the big map with DB data than clone/resize it to create the small preview. If it is a multiuser game, the updates will contain just changed tiles not all.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the unexplored area data on client side makes it really easy to source out, so unless if its an offline only game i would grab the tiles data from the database at the moment of exploration through ajax/ajaj, this way you have to download just the information that its needed at that moment.