# HTML Canvas w/ Image Cloning Issues

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I used tips + code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318565/any-way-to-clone-html5-canvas-element-with-its-content) to try to clone my original canvas - it contains an image with text overlaid on it. However, every time I run it, neither the image nor the text get copied, though the original works fine. Here is the javascript:

```html
<script>          
function CardText() {
            var title = document.calform.titleText.value;
            var badge = document.calform.badge.value;
            var encourage = document.calform.encourage.value;
            var description = document.calform.description.value;
            
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var x = canvas.width / 2;
      var y = canvas.height / 2;
      var imageObj = new Image();
      
      
      
      
        

      imageObj.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
        context.font = "25pt Helvetica";
        context.fillStyle = "white";
        context.textAlign = "center";
        context.fillText(title, x, 76);
        
        context.font = "18pt Arial";
        context.fillStyle = "white";
        context.textAlign = "center";
        context.fillText(badge, x-10, 311);
        
        context.font = "18pt Arial";
        context.fillStyle = "black";
        context.textAlign = "center";
        context.fillText(encourage, x, 380);
        
        context.font = "12pt Arial";
        context.fillStyle = "black";
        wrapText(context, description, x, 440, 280, 18);
        
        
        
        
      };
    

      imageObj.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/7wqLgSd.jpg';
     
            }
    function cloneCanvas(oldCanvas) {

        //create a new canvas
        var newCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var context = newCanvas.getContext('2d');
    

        //set dimensions
        newCanvas.width = oldCanvas.width;
        newCanvas.height = oldCanvas.height;

        //apply the old canvas to the new one
        context.drawImage(oldCanvas, 100, 300);
    
    
        //return the new canvas
        return newCanvas;
        }

        </script>
```

And I run it with an html button:

```html
 <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" align = 'center' type=button name=button1 value="COPY" onClick="cloneCanvas(canvas)">
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Edit: markE was kind enough to fix my problem, however it's not coming up within the full HTML document. Here's the full HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
     background-color:ivory;
     padding:10px;
     }
      
      #fills {
        position: relative;
        margin-left: 100px;
      }
      canvas{
        border:1px solid red;
        }
    </style>
   <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">  
  </head>
  <body>

   
        
        
        <script>
            
      

       var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
       var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

       var imageObj = new Image();
       imageObj.onload = function() {

      // create the original card canvas 
      // after the image has loaded
      CardText();

      // next clone the original card canvas
      // to a new canvas 
      var myNewCanvas=cloneCanvas(canvas);
      document.body.appendChild(myNewCanvas);

      };
      imageObj.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/7wqLgSd.jpg';


function CardText() {

  var title ="Title";// document.calform.titleText.value;
  var badge ="Badge";// document.calform.badge.value;
  var encourage ="Encourage";// document.calform.encourage.value;
  var description ="Description";// document.calform.description.value;

  var x = canvas.width / 2;
  var y = canvas.height / 2;

  context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);

  context.font = "25pt Helvetica";
  context.fillStyle = "white";
  context.textAlign = "center";
  context.fillText(title, x, 76);

  context.font = "18pt Arial";
  context.fillStyle = "white";
  context.textAlign = "center";
  context.fillText(badge, x-10, 311);

  context.font = "18pt Arial";
  context.fillStyle = "black";
  context.textAlign = "center";
  context.fillText(encourage, x, 380);

  context.font = "12pt Arial";
  context.fillStyle = "black";
  context.fillText(description, x, 440);
  //      wrapText(context, description, x, 440, 280, 18);

}


function cloneCanvas(oldCanvas) {

  //create a new canvas
  var newCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var context = newCanvas.getContext('2d');


  //set dimensions
  newCanvas.width = oldCanvas.width;
  newCanvas.height = oldCanvas.height;

  //apply the old canvas to the new one
  context.drawImage(oldCanvas, 100, 300);


  //return the new canvas
  return newCanvas;

}
        </script>
        <div id="fills" >
    <td align=right width=200>Title:</td>
        <td><input type=text name=titleText size=10 maxlength=10></td>
        
        <td align=right width=200>Badge Name:</td>
        <td><input type=text name=badge size=10 maxlength=10></td>
        
        <td align=right width=200>Encouraging Words:</td>
        <td><input type=text name=encourage size=10 maxlength=14></td>
        
        <td align=right width=200>Description:</td>
        <td><input type=text name=description size=50 maxlength=120></td>
            
    <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" align = 'center' type=button name=button1 value="Submit" onClick="CardText()">
        </div>
   
    
    
    
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="390" height="540"></canvas>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you might be calling `cloneCanvas` before `CardText` has a chance to fully load the image and draw the text on the image.

Try this refactoring which fully loads the image+text before trying to `cloneCanvas`.

[image]

Example Code and a Demo:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function() {

  // create the original card canvas 
  // after the image has loaded
  CardText();

  // next clone the original card canvas
  // to a new canvas 
  var myNewCanvas=cloneCanvas(canvas);
  document.body.appendChild(myNewCanvas);

};
imageObj.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/7wqLgSd.jpg';


function CardText() {

  var title ="Title";// document.calform.titleText.value;
  var badge ="Badge";// document.calform.badge.value;
  var encourage ="Encourage";// document.calform.encourage.value;
  var description ="Description";// document.calform.description.value;

  var x = canvas.width / 2;
  var y = canvas.height / 2;

  context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);

  context.font = "25pt Helvetica";
  context.fillStyle = "white";
  context.textAlign = "center";
  context.fillText(title, x, 76);

  context.font = "18pt Arial";
  context.fillStyle = "white";
  context.textAlign = "center";
  context.fillText(badge, x-10, 311);

  context.font = "18pt Arial";
  context.fillStyle = "black";
  context.textAlign = "center";
  context.fillText(encourage, x, 380);

  context.font = "12pt Arial";
  context.fillStyle = "black";
  context.fillText(description, x, 440);
  //      wrapText(context, description, x, 440, 280, 18);

}


function cloneCanvas(oldCanvas) {

  //create a new canvas
  var newCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var context = newCanvas.getContext('2d');


  //set dimensions
  newCanvas.width = oldCanvas.width;
  newCanvas.height = oldCanvas.height;

  //apply the old canvas to the new one
  context.drawImage(oldCanvas, 100, 300);


  //return the new canvas
  return newCanvas;

}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width=390 height=540></canvas>
```

**[ Addition: plugged my answer above into Allen Rabinovich's code. ]**

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function() {

  // create the original card canvas 
  // after the image has loaded
  CardText();


};
imageObj.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/7wqLgSd.jpg';

document.getElementById('drawAll').onclick=function(){
  CardText();
  // next clone the original card canvas
  // to a new canvas 
  var myNewCanvas=cloneCanvas(canvas);
  document.body.appendChild(myNewCanvas);
}


function CardText() {

  var title=document.getElementsByName('titleText')[0].value;
  var badge=document.getElementsByName('badge')[0].value;
  var encourage=document.getElementsByName('encourage')[0].value;
  var description=document.getElementsByName('description')[0].value;

  var x = canvas.width / 2;
  var y = canvas.height / 2;

  context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);

  context.font = "25pt Helvetica";
  context.fillStyle = "white";
  context.textAlign = "center";
  context.fillText(title, x, 76);

  context.font = "18pt Arial";
  context.fillStyle = "white";
  context.textAlign = "center";
  context.fillText(badge, x-10, 311);

  context.font = "18pt Arial";
  context.fillStyle = "black";
  context.textAlign = "center";
  context.fillText(encourage, x, 380);

  context.font = "12pt Arial";
  context.fillStyle = "black";
  context.fillText(description, x, 440);
  //      wrapText(context, description, x, 440, 280, 18);

}


function cloneCanvas(oldCanvas) {

  //create a new canvas
  var newCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var context = newCanvas.getContext('2d');


  //set dimensions
  newCanvas.width = oldCanvas.width;
  newCanvas.height = oldCanvas.height;

  //apply the old canvas to the new one
  context.drawImage(oldCanvas,0,0);


  //return the new canvas
  return newCanvas;

}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
#fills{ position: relative; margin-left: 100px; }
```

```html
Title:<input type=text name=titleText size=10 maxlength=10><br>
Badge:<input type=text name=badge size=10 maxlength=10><br>
Encourage:<input type=text name=encourage size=10 maxlength=14><br>
Description:<input type=text name=description size=50 maxlength=120><br>
<input id=drawAll class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" align = 'center' type=button name=button1 value="Submit">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="390" height="540"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help, I am very grateful. However, it's not working for me somehow. I can clearly see that the snippet is working perfectly, so it's adding to my confusion. Perhaps adding the full HTML document will illuminate something I'm clearly messing up. Thank you again.

Comment: I added to my answer to plug my code into your html. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Amazing stuff, thank you! I don't have enough rep to upvote you, I'm sorry about that :(