# angular.copy is failing to copy an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas

I am using angular to make a deep copy of a canvas object, and I am getting `Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to read the 'selectionDirection' property from 'HTMLInputElement': The input element's type ('checkbox') does not support selection.`

```
canvas = document.getElementById('workercanvas')
canvas.width = cfg.labelsImage.width
canvas.height = cfg.labelsImage.height
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

clonedCanvas = null

if clonedCanvas is null
   clonedCanvas = angular.copy(canvas)
```

Any thoughts? Can angular.copy copy DOM elements?

**UPDATE: use angular.element.clone**
I tried using angular.element.clone, the problem with that is that it seems that it doesnt make a deep copy, I have the following:

```
imgObj = new Image(imgWidth, imgHeight)
imgObj.onload = ->
ctx.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight)
if clonedCanvas is null
    clonedCanvas = angular.element.clone(canvas)
    clonedImg = angular.element.clone(imgObj)
    clonedCanvasContext = clonedCanvas.getContext('2d')
    clonedCanvasContext.drawImage(clonedImg, 0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight)
```

When I am changing the imgObj this also affects the clonedImg and changes the clonedCanvas, I want somehow to keep the original information. Is `angular.element.clone` make a deep copy?

Comment: `Can angular.copy copy DOM elements?`. No.

Comment: @dfsq any suggested solution on that?

Comment: Use [element.clone()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

Comment: You need to clone DOM node, not a simple JS object. See above comment from @Blazemonger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`element.clone()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) to clone DOM elements -- it's Angular's version of [jQuery `clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).

Comment: This will probably not copy the content of canvas, only the element.

Comment: although it copies the element, as I can see that is not a deep copy, its more reference.

Comment: That's a [separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318565/any-way-to-clone-html5-canvas-element-with-its-content). You ordinarily do a deep copy with [`.clone(true,true)`](http://api.jquery.com/clone)