# Can html2canvas capture a javascript 3d 'screenshot'?

Tags: javascript, 3d, html2canvas

I have seen an example of html2canvas create a 'screenshot' of an html block (ex: [html2canvas example](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/examples.html)).

What I would like to do is, using javascript, capture a 'screenshot' of a three.js (or any js 3d library) scene.

Keep in mind that the user might play with (rotate, etc) the 3d scene  before deciding to 'screenshot' it.

Can html2canvas 'capture' a 3d scene?

**EDIT**
        `see plunker for code`[see plunker for working solution](http://plnkr.co/edit/Znl8c05ZT1o785pORx7U?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since three.js draws a canvas, I'm pretty sure you'd be able to replicate it's current state without the use of html2canvas.

```
function cloneCanvas(oldCanvas) {
    //create a new canvas
    var newCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var context = newCanvas.getContext('2d');

    //set dimensions
    newCanvas.width = oldCanvas.width;
    newCanvas.height = oldCanvas.height;

    //apply the old canvas to the new one
    context.drawImage(oldCanvas, 0, 0);

    //return the new canvas
    return newCanvas;
}
```

[Thanks to Robert Hurst for his answer on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318565/any-way-to-clone-html5-canvas-element-with-its-content)

Regarding html2canvas, this paragraph of the doc leads me to believe that it will be able to copy the canva since it is not tainted with cross-origin content.

> Limitations
>   All the images that the script uses need to reside under the same origin for it to be able to read them without the assistance of a proxy. Similarly, if you have other canvas elements on the page, which have been tainted with cross-origin content, they will become dirty and no longer readable by html2canvas.

Comment: the html2canvasis taking dom elements and rendering them on a canvas ... BUT the three.js is _already_ on a canvas ... so, yes, there is no need for html2canvas ... thanks ...