# How to create a screenshot that will include three.js canvases and html with CSS

Tags: reactjs, blob, html2canvas, webpage-screenshot

I have a React app that displays a toolbar and 2 canvases built-in Three.js. I would like to take a screenshot of the entire app.
I tried already niklasvh/html2canvas

```
        const element = document.getElementsByClassName("contentContainer-5")[0] as HTMLElement;
        const url = html2canvas(element)
            .then((canvas)=> {
                return canvas.toDataURL();
            })
        }
        const screenshotObject = {
            url: url,
            width: 128,
            height: 64,
        }

        return screenshotObject
    }
```

and BLOB html5

```
takeScreenshot() {
        const screenshot = document.documentElement
            .cloneNode(true) as Element;
        const blob = new Blob([screenshot.outerHTML], {
            type: 'text/html'
        });
        return blob;
    }
    
    generate() {
        window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        window.open(window.URL
            .createObjectURL(this.takeScreenshot()));
    }
```

In the first case, the screenshot's URL is very long but the image is empty.
In the second case, HTML and CSS is perfectly snapshotted but canvases are empty.

Answer (score 0):

`.cloneNode()` only copies the DOM and canvasses are not a part of DOM. A workround could be done with the cloneNode function ([as done here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41242597/16045352))

```js
const takeScreenshot = () => {
  const _cloneNodeFn = HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.cloneNode;

  HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.cloneNode = function () {
    const customCloneNodeFn = _cloneNodeFn.apply(this, arguments);

    if (this.getContext("2d")) {
      customCloneNodeFn.getContext("2d").drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    }

    return customCloneNodeFn;
  };
};

const _canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
_canvas.getContext("2d").fillRect(20, 20, 20, 20);

for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  document.body.appendChild(_canvas.cloneNode());
}
```

**Note: `cloneNode` has to be called on the canvas directly, and not the parent node.**

Answer (score 0):

In order to take a screenshot of a `Three.js` scene using Javascript, you need to create a new canvas context with the original canvas' properties, draw the image onto the context, convert it to a blob, then make it available on an invisible `a` tag which is automatically click and downloads a screenshot of your Three.js scene.

I created the following barebones code that takes screenshots of scenes:

```js
export const screenshot = async (idx) => {
    const element = document.getElementById('existing-canvas-id');
    const canvas = document.createElement('new-canvas-id');
    
    canvas.width = element.width;
    canvas.height = element.height;

    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    let url = element.toDataURL();
    let img = new Image();
    
    await new Promise(r => img.onload=r, img.src=url);
    
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    const blob = canvas.toBlob();
    const link = document.createElement('a');

    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download = `${index}.png`;
    link.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
  }
};
```