# How to use a html5 canvas that is based on ID twice on same page

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm working on canvas here I want to use same canvas multiple times on the same page I tried using the class name `getElementsByClassName` and using query selector also. but it's not working. Can anyone point me in the right direction what might be the issue here how can I achieve? in both boxes box1, box2 I want to add same canvas.

```js
const noise = () => {
    let canvas, ctx;
    let wWidth, wHeight;
    let noiseData = [];
    let frame = 0;
    let loopTimeout;

    // Create Noise
    const createNoise = () => {
        const idata = ctx.createImageData(wWidth, wHeight);
        const buffer32 = new Uint32Array(idata.data.buffer);
        const len = buffer32.length;

        for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
                buffer32[i] = 0xff000000;
            }
        }

        noiseData.push(idata);
    };

    // Play Noise
    const paintNoise = () => {
        if (frame === 9) {
            frame = 0;
        } else {
            frame++;
        }
        ctx.putImageData(noiseData[frame], 0, 0);
    };


    // Loop
    const loop = () => {
        paintNoise(frame);
        loopTimeout = window.setTimeout(() => {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
        }, (1000 / 25));
    };


    // Setup
    const setup = () => {
        wWidth = window.innerWidth;
        wHeight = window.innerHeight;

        canvas.width = wWidth;
        canvas.height = wHeight;

        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            createNoise();
        }
        loop();
    };


    // Reset
    let resizeThrottle;
    const reset = () => {
        window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
            window.clearTimeout(resizeThrottle);

            resizeThrottle = window.setTimeout(() => {
                window.clearTimeout(loopTimeout);
                setup();
            }, 200);
        }, false);
    };


    // Init
    const init = (() => {
         canvas = document.getElementById('noise');
        //canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('noise');
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        setup();
    })();
};
noise();
```

```css
.noise {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;   
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: .5;
}
.box1, .box2 {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 20px;
    background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
    <canvas id="noise" class="noise"></canvas>
</div>

<div class="box2">
    <canvas id="noise" class="noise"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't have two of the same ids on the page, it's going to give you weird side effects. Use the class instead. getElementById will only every select one element.

Comment: @SpeedOfRound yeah that's the reason I tried using the class name.

Comment: Then _show us_ what you actually tried. Explain your reasoning for the changes you made.

Comment: @04FS ` var canvases = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('noise'));
        for (let canvas of canvases) {
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        }`  or  ` canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('noise');
        ctx = canvas[0].getContext('2d');`

Comment: you're overwriting ctx, which createnoise uses as the canvas. Please update your question, it's too difficult so see how things go together like this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't add the same element to two locations at once. If you just want a copy of the element, you can use cloneNode (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode)   You can do something like `const myCanvas = document.querySelector("canvas.whateverClass"); document.body.appendChild(myCanvas.cloneNode(true));`

Comment: @Cat can you please add the snippet of your code.

Comment: I don't have any more code to put in a snippet. My comment was just showing how to duplicate an element (just select it, call cloneNode on it, and append it to a container element on the page.) This is the closest you can get to using the same html element twice on the same page (although an argument could be made that using a <template> gets you closer.)  If you don't care about reusing the <canvas> itself but just want the same image from that canvas in a new canvas, you can use this technique: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318565/any-way-to-clone-html5-canvas-element-with-its-content

Answer (score 0):

Use `getElementsByClassName`. You will get an array then. For instance for class `box`:

```
canvas = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

for (i = 0; i < canvas.length; i++) { //...do smth here...// }
```

Comment: Actually it doesn't returns an array, it returns an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). Not *a lot* of differences, but for example, `document.getElementsByClassNames('some-class').forEach(() => {})` is invalid