# How to store a canvas into a variable, and then render it at later point?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, canvas

The idea is that you can paint on the canvas, then store it into a variable and move on with other paintings, etc. Then, if you want, reopen that previously painting on the canvas, from the variable.

There's only one canvas element.

This is how I tried to solve that without a result:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

-

```
canvas: HtmlCanvasElement;
ctx1: any;
storedCanvas: HTMLCanvasElement;
ctx2: any;

ngAfterviewInit(){
  this.canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
}

saveCanvas(){
  this.storedCanvas = this.canvas;
}

loadCanvas(){
this.canvas.replaceWith(this.storedCanvas); 
}
```

Whatever I did after using **saveCanvas()**, the changes affect **storedCanvas** as well, e.g.:

1) Draw

2) Save

3) Make some changes without saving

4) Load the canvas, the changes from 3) affected **storedCanvas** as well, meaning **canvas** and **storedCanvas** still identical even after the save.

I assume this is not even close to how you're supposed to store and render a canvas.

Comment: because you still only ever create one canvas...

Comment: @ASDFGerte Is it possible to store canvas value into a variable? It won't be a pretty solution if I put multiple canvas elements in HTML.

Comment: Take a look here [serialize a canvas](https://konvajs.org/docs/data_and_serialization/Serialize_a_Stage.html) Note: this works for simple canvas.

Comment: Don't misunderstand. You did store your canvas into a variable (and as all javascript objects, by reference). Then you change the canvas. Whether you stored it in a variable or not doesn't matter here, it's still only one canvas, and you change it. For copying a canvas, refer to [any-way-to-clone-html5-canvas-element-with-its-content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318565/any-way-to-clone-html5-canvas-element-with-its-content).

Comment: @ASDFGerte Ah, I misunderstood. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create the first canvas in the document, and then get a reference to it like so:

```
this.canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById('myCanvas');
```

Now `this.canvas` is a reference to your first canvas.

You then copy the same reference to a second variable:

```
this.storedCanvas = this.canvas
```

So now `this.storedCanvas` and `this.canvas` are the same canvas.

What you need to do is create a second canvas using:

```
const mySecondCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
mySecondCanvas.id = "mySecondCanvas";
```

To see the canvas you'll then need to append it the the document body using:

```
document.body.appendChild(mySecondCanvas);
```

Read up about reference types vs value types, as `HTMLCanvasElement` is a reference type. When you assign it to a second variable, it doesn't copy the whole object, it just copies the reference to the same object.