# Creating a Path/Imagemap from a Transparent PNG with Raphael JS

Tags: javascript, raphael

I'm working on a Raphael JS project and need to display some transparent PNGs with only the parts that are non-transparent to be clickable. Is there a way to:

- Upon mouse click, pull out the alpha of the current position.
  or
- Generate a path which can be be used to define the clickable region (i.e. http://raphaeljs.com/australia.html)

Answer (score 0):

As raphael is for vector graphics, it is the wrong tool for your problem with png. I think canvas is what you looking for. [Load your image in an canvas](http://www.phpied.com/photo-canvas-tag-flip/) (the canvas doesent need to be pushed in the DOM). On click check the coords and [get the pixel out of the canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/html/canvas/pixel_manipulation_with_canvas#Getting_the_pixel_data_for_a_context).

But maybe it will be easier to convert you png to vector graphics and use raphael instead.

Comment: I'd go completely with canvas except that there's a lot more to this piece. I believe I can however use canvas and determine the alpha and do something with it (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667045/getpixel-from-html-canvas).

Comment: Yes you can. But svg is build for something like this (detect mouseover), where you have to rebuild the feature with canvas.