# Is there any way to do color transforms on bitmaps using HTML5 / CSS / Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, colors, webkit, bitmap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [getPixel from HTML Canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667045/getpixel-from-html-canvas)

I've looked around quite a bit for an answer to this question. Kind of surprised to have not found a definitive answer.

Is there any way to do color transforms on bitmaps in modern browsers using either javascript, css or any of the webkit css effects? Examples would be being able to desaturate a JEPG, or adjust the R,G and B values...I know there is a new hsla attribute to the color property in CSS3, but it doesn't seem to work on bitmaps.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667045/getpixel-from-html-canvas

Answer (score 1):

Pixastic is a great project (as mistabell mentions). If you want more simpler or customized effects read up on the Canvas tag and it js api.

Comment: Thanks! Looks pretty cool, though seems computationally heavy. Processing each pixel? Yeesh!

Comment: I was also pointed to this, looks really nice: http://mezzoblue.com/archives/2010/10/07/paintbrushjs/