# HTML5 canvas getPixel

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I was create one scribbling application in HTML5(using canvas).I want save current work and retrieve that(like a file) also do modification later.How can i do that.
Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Canvas2Image](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/), it seems to support PNG, JPEG and BMP.

Comment: Actually i don't want like a Image.I want co-ordinates from start point to end point in array

Comment: Okay, look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667045/getpixel-from-html-canvas).