# How can I display letters using html table cells as colored pixels?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, cell

Let's say I have an html table (50 x 50 cells) with a yellow background. I would like to use the background colors of the cells to print letters (A-Z) (e.g. some cells blue and most cells yellow) in an animated loop, using jQuery. I can create a table and a pointer which can loop through all the cells of the table such that it can change the background color of a particular cell (x,y) to different color. However, I don't understand which cells to highlight to form a particular letter. For example, to display the letter "A" on the 50 x 50 grid, which cells do I need to change to a new background color such that I get the letter A displayed on the screen with the cells, and so on for all the other letters. Is there any pattern for this?

Comment: I can't quit grasp what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Am i correct in the assumption that you are trying to implement some obscure CAPTCHA or something?

Comment: Not really. I just want to create an animation such that, it would display a persons' name in a loop. For example "Kai" would display K first followed by A, then I

Comment: There's no shortcut to happiness here. Take your favorite graphics editor, create a new image sized 50x50 pixels, insert a character and see which pixels it occupies.

Comment: Or if you're not married to tables you could draw a character to a 50x50 canvas and scale it up.

Comment: I still don't get how the described table (50x50) correlates to an alphabet? Do you have the table ready and just want to highlight certain cells in regards of some input string?

Comment: @camlover: Stop vandalizing your question.

Answer (score 6):

Create the cells with a loop such as:

```
for(var i=65;i<=90;i++) {
    console.log(String.fromCharCode(i));
 }
```

(65 is the char code for `A`, 90 for `Z`).
in the loop, attach id with the char. something like "charA", "charB".
Than you can access the fields searching the id <"char" + letter>.

if you know only the (x,y) in the 50x50 grid, calculate which letter it is with:

```
String.fromCharCode(65+y*50+x);
```

Or take the value of it from the elment itself

```
$(this).val();
```

Or from attribute you attach to it:

```
$(this).attr('letter')
```

Comment: I don't want to print letter on a single cell. I want the letter to occupy the grid completely using number of different cells.

Comment: To be precise i want to display shape of the alphabet on the 50 x 50 grid

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question. Added a new answer

Answer (score 1):

Use Canvas (Edit: only for the generation of the letter coordinates in the 50x50 grid, no usage of canvas afterwards).

- For each letter possible, print the char on a 50x50 html5/javascript canvas in black and white using something like:
  http://typeface.neocracy.org/examples.html
- Then access the canvas in each pixel to check if it black or white, and save it in multidimensional javascript arrays.
  [getPixel from HTML Canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667045/getpixel-from-html-canvas)
- print the output and create javascript code or JSON object that saves those coordinates for your use.

After that you'll have all you need: the coordinates for each letter, and (bonus) with a font of your choice.

Comment: Logically it should work, however, I don't plan on using html5 canvas. Any other workaround?

Comment: The usage of the canvas is only for the generation of the coordinates, you don't use it afterwards in your code!