# Identify certain colors using getImageData

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm not sure how to properly use `getImageData` for color recognition.

```
var imgd = ctx.getImageData(checkx - ln, checky - ln, ln * 2, ln * 2);
pix = imgd.data;

for (var i = 0, n = pix.length; i < n; i += 4){
    if (pix[i] != 255) {
        collision = 1;
    }
}
```

Right now, to be safe - if something isn't white on the canvas -> collision

But I want to identify red `#ff0000` or green colors `#00CC00`

How can I do it?

Comment: Why do you think that code would recognize white? It does set `collision` to `1` only when the *red* intensity is not `255`.

Comment: Why are you performing an assignment in the conditional of the loop?

Comment: I need a way to recognize certain colors on the canvas and I have no idea how to do it

Comment: I don't know what you are getting in each pix[] entity, but white would be 16777215 surely?  As opposed to 255.  255 represents only a single plane.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV

Comment: Just read something interesting here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667045/getpixel-from-html-canvas

Comment: I'm also very new to html5 and I'm not sure what to do

Comment: @Bergi - The question was modified by myself and one other to correct the conditional.  That's why it is now correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with, you need an image loaded on the canvas. You may try [my fiddle on loading images](http://jsfiddle.net/AliasM2K/tAum2/) for more information.

Once an image is loaded onto the canvas, the pixel level information of the loaded image can be obtained using the `data` method of `ImageData` object.

Before that, the `ImageData` object must be generated from the canvas. First statement of the script

```
var imgd = ctx.getImageData(checkx - ln, checky - ln, ln * 2, ln * 2);
```

does just that.

Second statement in the script,

```
pix = imgd.data;
```

retrieves pixel level details of the image loaded into the canvas as [Unit8ClampedArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Typed_arrays/Uint8ClampedArray)

The variable `pix` can be treated as any ordinary array. For example

```
for(var nPix = 0; nPix < pix.length; nPix++) {
  //Some pixel manipulation on the image
}
```

Hope this inspired some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I really am unfamiliar with the API, so this is a long shot.  If my assumption that pix[n] represents a single pixel RGB value, then this will tell you if there is any red in the pixel:

```
if (0xff0000 & pix[i]) {
    gotSomeRed = true;
}
```

*Update:* If that is the case, then a collision will also be:

```
if (0xffffff & pix[i]) {
    gotACollision = true;
}
```

*Update 2:*

Apparently, the API says:

```
red = imgData.data[0];
green = imgData.data[1];
blue = imgData.data[2];
alpha = imgData.data[3];
```

So you can achieve what I outlined by either:

```
if (pix[0] & 0xff) {
    gotSomeRed = true;
}
if (((pix[0] << 16) | (pix[1] << 8) | pix[2]) === 0xffffff) {
    gotAWhitePixel = true;
}
```

Or simply:

```
if (pix[0] > 0) {
    gotSomeRed = true;
}
if ((pix[0] + pix[1] + pix[2]) === 0xffffff) {
    gotAWhitePixel = true;
}
```

Comment: I won't downvote, but please make yourself familiar with [the API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) and then either update or delete your answer :-)