# Get Pixel Color from Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am creating a color picker using javascript and the HTML5 canvas. I'm attempting to use the following code to get the color of a specific pixel on the color picker, but it just returns black every time: `rgb(0, 0, 0)`. However, if I replace `this.getGradientPos.X` and `this.getGradientPos.Y` with hard-coded values, it works fine. It also works if only one of the `X` or `Y` variables is in place and the other is hard-coded. In the console, `curGradPos.X` and `curGradPos.Y` both show correct positions. I'm at a loss as to what could be wrong.

```
ColorPicker.prototype.getGradientColor =
function()
{   
    j = this.context.getImageData(this.curGradPos.X, this.curGradPos.Y, 1, 1);
    k = j.data;
    console.log(this.curGradPos);
    console.log(k);

    return {r: k[0], g: k[1], b: k[2]};
}
```

This initializes the variables.

```
function ColorPicker()
{
    this.canvas = document.getElementById('colorPicker');

    this.curColor = this.baseColor = {r: 255, g: 0, b: 0};
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

    this.curGradPos = {X: 255, Y: 255};
}
```

And this updates the curGradPos variable on mousemove.

```
rect = this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
x = event.clientX - rect.left;
y = event.clientY - rect.top;

if (x >= 15 && x < 15+255 && y >= 15 && y < 15+255)
{
    this.curGradPos = {X: x, Y: y}; //seems to be correct
    this.drawColorGradient();
    this.curColor = this.getGradientColor(); //above function with issue
}
```

Comment: Please show the code (or the essential part of it) so we can see how context, curGradPos comes about.

Comment: possible duplicate of [getPixel from HTML Canvas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667045/getpixel-from-html-canvas)

Comment: @ColinE not a duplicate IMHO - the OP clearly knows _approximately_ how to retrieve a pixel, the question is why this specific code is allegedly failing.

Comment: @shaqb4 Your code appears to be generally correct.  please create a jsfiddle that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Do you create an instance by using new, e.g `var cp = new ColorPicker()`

Comment: I successfully retrieved and manipulated pixels in other parts of the code. Just this one function isn't working for some reason. And yes, I create an instance.

Comment: Are you trying to pick a color from an image, and if so, is the image loaded from same origin (server/scheme) or is the image from a cross-origin source?

Comment: I don't use an image, I just draw a gradient. My code is hosted at http://shaqzone.com/skinapp/. You're supposed to be able to draw the chosen color on the avatar.

Comment: @shaqb4 What is `this` pointing to in your last code block? Is this wrapped in a function? If so, you mustn't specify that function as a (direct) mousemove callback because `this` = `DOMElement` in that case. **/Edit:** You're correctly attaching the event handler according to your live site.

Comment: Ken- I saw your last answer about the marker and dealt with it. It seems to work now, as far as I can tell :). I'm not sure what you mean in your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code seem to read the color from the marker rather than the color "behind" it.

The color needs to be read from the position and then set the marker or you will get the color of the marker instead in that position; and of course as the marker is black that color will be returned each time.