# How do I retrieve raw bitmap data from html5 canvas using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, bitmap

I would like to know how to extract the raw data from a html5 canvas as raw bitmap pixel data and store it in a variable.

So far I have setup my html5 canvas with an image in it:
https://jsfiddle.net/t21mjh5L/1/

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var img = document.getElementById("myimg");
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
var bitmapData;
//retrieve image data as raw bitmap
```

Comment: Have you seen [this older question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667045/getpixel-from-html-canvas)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try to get bitmap data like this :

```
var myImageData = ctx.getImageData(left, top, width, height).data;
```

More information about getting image data can be found
[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas)

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helped me find this article which helped me get where I wanted. https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/12/faster-canvas-pixel-manipulation-with-typed-arrays/

Comment: Also if anyone is interested this is how you can get raw jpeg data:  
var jpegRawData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0).replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,","");