# How to read individual pixel transparency values from a user submitted PNG on the front-end?

Tags: javascript, html, image, png, pixel

I need to read the transparency value for each pixel of a user submitted PNG, on the front-end.

Right now I'm blocking the form submission and I convert the PNG in the file input to a FileReader object. Now I was thinking that I could simply read the transparency values out of that data. For example, I converted to ArrayBuffer and then to Uint8Array, and that's a large array of ints whose values range from 0-255, but it doesn't look like the right colors.

Then I read that you must actually display the PNG on an HTML5 canvas in order to do this.

Answer (score 1):

the png buffer don't hold the pixel data in a readable way, it's compressed so you can't read it like you would like to. you have to get the pixels somehow, the easiest straight forward way is to use [createImageBitmap(file)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CreateImageBitmap) to turn it into a bitmap and then use the [OffscreenCanvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas) to paint the bitmap and read it using `getImageData`
This way you can read more than just pngs... and also using it in worker threads

```js
// simulate getting a file you would get from eg file input (1x1 pixel)
fetch('data:;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==')
  .then(r => r.blob())
  .then(createImageBitmap)
  .then(readData)

/** @param {ImageBitmap} bitmap */
function readData (bitmap) {
  const { width: w, height: h } = bitmap
  const canvas = new OffscreenCanvas(w, h)
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

  ctx.drawImage(bitmap, 0, 0)
  const pixels = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, w, h).data

  // read alpha channel
  for (let i = 0; i < pixels.length; i += 4) {
    console.log(pixels[i + 3])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PNG does not contain the raw image data, but is compressed. In order to decode it, you need to do some complex calculations. Load it into a `<canvas>` and let the browser do the decoding:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
<input type="file" accept="image/png, image/gif, image/jpeg" id="myFileInput" />
<script>
    const canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
    const fileInput = document.getElementById('myFileInput');

    fileInput.onchange = function(changeEvent) {
        const files = changeEvent.target.files;
        const file = files[0];
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = function(loadEvent){
            const image = new Image();
            image.src = loadEvent.target.result;
            canvas.width = image.width;
            canvas.height = image.height;
            context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

            const imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
            console.log(imageData)
            // see https://stackoverflow.com/a/667074/17870699
        }  
    };
</script>
```

Comment: a faster approach would be to use URL.createObjectURL instead of using the FileReader

Comment: ...and also using [img.decode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/decode) instead of onload...